# create database structure using .sql file and FMDB

Tags: objective-c, ios6, sqlite, fmdb

I have a .sql file which I have exported from **MySQL**. I am trying to add that table structure into **SQLite** using `FMDB framework` but it is not executed and always **`return false`**. Here is the structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` (
`admin_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`admin_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

What I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: You may need some tools.Try http://www.sqlitemanager.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That SQL doesn't conform to SQLite's `CREATE TABLE` syntax as [documented online](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html). If you look at the FMDB [`lastErrorMessage`](http://ccgus.github.io/fmdb/html/Classes/FMDatabase.html#//api/name/lastErrorMessage) method (which is analogous to [`sqlite3_errmsg`](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/errcode.html)), it will report the specifics regarding the error.

Notably, the `AUTO_INCREMENT` syntax is not correct. Even if you fix that, the `ENGINE` and `DEFAULT CHARSET` options won't be recognized, either. At the very minimum, you'd have to try something like:

```
NSString *sql = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `admin` ("
                "`admin_id` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
                "`first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
                "`last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
                "`email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
                "`password` varchar(30) NOT NULL,"
                "`date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,"
                "`status` tinyint(2) NOT NULL"
                ")";
```

Or, given that SQLite won't understand some of those data types (though with SQLite's "dynamic type system", it doesn't really matter), you might want to replace `varchar(30)` with `TEXT` and `tinyint(2)` with `INTEGER` and `datetime` with whatever format you plan on storing dates. See [Data Types](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) discussion.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use MySQL extensions in another database.

You should at least replace the `admin_id` type with `INTEGER`, replace `AUTO_INCREMENT` with `AUTOINCREMENT`, and remove the `ENGINE` and `DEFAULT CHARSET` settings.

Answer (score -1):

- (IBAction)findContact:(UIButton *)sender {

  const char *dbPath = [databasePath UTF8String];
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;

  if (sqlite3_open(dbPath, &contactDB)== SQLITE_OK) {
      NSString *querySQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT ADDRESS,PHONE FROM CONTACTS WHERE NAME = \"%@\"",_name.text];
      const char *query_stmt = [querySQL UTF8String];
      if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(contactDB, query_stmt, -1, &statement, NULL)== SQLITE_OK)
      {

  ```
      if (sqlite3_step(statement)== SQLITE_ROW) {

          NSString *addressField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0)];
          _address.text = addressField;
          NSString *phoneField = [[NSString alloc]initWithUTF8String:(const char *) sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
          _phoneNo.text = phoneField;
          _status.text = @"Match Found";
      }else{
          _status.text = @"Match not found";
          _address.text = @"";
          _phoneNo.text = @"";
      }
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  }
  sqlite3_close(contactDB);
  }
  ```

}